# Why Microsoft Defender Offline scan won’t work?

Tags: anti-virus, windows-defender

When i try to do scan, my computer shows screen with Windows Defender Offline scan loading and then just after minute restarts and never finishes scan. Why it does that, can i somehow fix it?

Comment: How are you trying to scan?

Comment: by going to scan options and choosing Microsoft Defender Offline and then scan now

Comment: Isn't that what Defender Offline is supposed to do? It should download a self-contained scanner and reboot into it IIRC. The problem is that it's booting Windows rather than the scanner.

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible you have a virus that is turning off Microsoft Defender? You might try another scanner to see if you have something that Microsoft Defender is missing. One that I use is Trend Micro Housecall at https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/forHome/products/housecall.html

Good luck!